# Eigenvalue characteristic equation help

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I am just trying to work through this example, however I do not seem to get the same expression for the characteristic equation, no matter what I try. Hoping someone could help?

$det  \begin{vmatrix} a_{12}-1-\lambda & a_{12}(a_{12}-1) \\ \rho a_{21}(a_{21}-1)  & \rho(a_{21}-1)-\lambda  \end{vmatrix}  $

I should get

**$ \lambda^{2} + ( 1-a_{12}+ \rho(1-a_{21}))\lambda + \rho(1-a_{21})(1-a_{12})(1-a_{12}a_{21}) $**

However I only can get the first and second terms, not the constant term!

$ (a_{12}-1-\lambda)(\rho a_{21}-\rho-\lambda)  - a_{12}(a_{12}-1)(\rho a_{21}(a_{21}-1) = 0 $

$ \rho a_{12}a_{21}  - a_{12}\rho - a_{12}\lambda - \rho a_{21} + \rho + \lambda - \rho a_{21}\lambda + \rho\lambda + \lambda^{2}$

$ \lambda^{2} -a_{12} \lambda + \lambda -\rho a_{21} \lambda + \rho \lambda $

$\lambda^{2} + ( 1-a_{12} -\rho a_{21} + \rho) \lambda$

$ \lambda^{2} + ( 1-a12+ \rho(1-a21))\lambda $

However the constant terms I can't seem to do much with,

I am left with $ \rho a_{12}a_{21} - a_{12} \rho - \rho a_{21} + \rho - a_{12}(a_{12}-1) \rho a_{21}(a_{21}-1) $ Which i ccan seem to factor, caan someone please help me with this thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant is
$$
((a_{12}-1)-\lambda)(\rho(a_{21}-1)-\lambda)-\rho a_{21}(a_{21}-1)a_{12}(a_{12}-1)
$$
which becomes
$$
\rho(a_{12}-1)(a_{21}-1)-\rho a_{12}a_{21}(a_{12}-1)(a_{21}-1)
-\lambda(a_{12}-1-\rho(a_{21}-1))+\lambda^2
$$
The constant term is
$$
\rho(a_{12}-1)(a_{21}-1)(1-a_{12}a_{21})
$$

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I dont know why i expanded everything out, i didnt think i could treat the terms as 'one'. Thank you,.